# A more complex rolling sum over the next n rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
print(df)
  day     month    year    quantity    
   6       04      2018       10
   8       04      2018        8
  12       04      2018        8
```

I would like to create a column, **sum** of the "quantity" over the next **"n"** days, as it follows:

```
n = 2

print(df1)
  day     month    year    quantity  final_quantity    
   6       04      2018       10     10 + 0 + 8 = 18
   8       04      2018        8      8 + 0 + 0 = 8
  12       04      2018        8      8 + 0 + 0 = 8
```

Specifically, summing **0** if the product has **not** been sold in the next "n" days.
I tried rolling sums from Pandas, but does not seem to work on different columns:

```
n = 2
df.quantity[::-1].rolling(n + 1, min_periods=1).sum()[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])

df['final_quantity'] = [df.loc[df['DateTime'].between(d, d+pd.Timedelta(days=2)), 'quantity'].sum() \
                        for d in df['DateTime']]

print(df)

#    day  month  year  quantity   DateTime  final_quantity
# 0    6      4  2018        10 2018-04-06              18
# 1    8      4  2018         8 2018-04-08               8
# 2   12      4  2018         8 2018-04-12               8
```

Comment: It does not seem to be working; specifically, it does not count months and years @jpp

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set_index` and `rolling` with `sum`:

```
df_out = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['month'].astype(str)+
                            df['day'].astype(str)+
                            df['year'].astype(str), format='%m%d%Y'))['quantity']
d1 = df_out.resample('D').asfreq(fill_value=0)
d2 = d1[::-1].reset_index()
df['final_quantity'] = d2['quantity'].rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum()[::-1].to_frame()\
                                     .set_index(d1.index)\
                                     .reindex(df_out.index).values
```

Output:

```
   day  month  year  quantity  final_quantity
0    6      4  2018        10            18.0
1    8      4  2018         8             8.0
2   12      4  2018         8             8.0
```

Comment: But you're not creating the "final_quantity" column, are you?

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli You were right.  In order to use rolling forward on time period, I think you have to some juggling of indexes and datetime columns.  Using resample to get a record for each day, then you can reverse the order to simulate rolling forward and sum. The reorder back to chronological and reindex on original records.